# Replace an item in a list by another item

Tags: python, list

I have to replace in a list the multiples of `5` by the number + `x`. For example, if I have the list `[1,3,5,7,9,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29]`, the result has to be `[1,3,5x,7,9,11,13,15x,17,19,21,23,25x,27,29]`. I have tried to develop the script but it doesn't work, can anyone help me?

```py
numbers = list (range(1,31))

odds = [number for number in numbers if number % 2 == 1]

print(odds)

for index, value in enumerate(odds):
   
    if value%5==0:
        odds[index] = '5x'

print(odds)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have tried to develop the script but it doesn't work, can anyone help me?" Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. We need a *specific* question here - it should be clear what help you need, what it is that you don't understand for yourself. That starts with showing your understanding of the problem - *what do you mean*, "it doesn't work"? *What happens* when you run the program, and *how is that different* from what you want to happen?

Comment: As an aside, please read the documentation for `range` and see if you can think of a simpler way to create `odds`.

Comment: "I have to replace in a list the multiples of 5 by the number + x" Look closely at the part of your code that does the replacement. What value do you replace things with? Do you see why that causes a problem? Do you know how to write the code so that the replacement is instead "the number + x" as you describe? If not, then specifically what is the problem?

Comment: The input list has two 9s but one seems to have disappeared from the output

Answer (score 0):

We can solve your problem by using the value variable, which stores the current number. We just need to reference this variable when setting the current element to add to "x", like this:

```
odds[index] = str(value) + "x"
```

Notice the need to cast value as a string, as we cannot concatinate an integer and a string without creating a touple.

Comment: Or you could use f'{value}x'

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code much simpler:

```
numbers = range(1, 31, 2)
res = [str(i) + 'x' if i%5 == 0 else i for i in numbers]
print(res)
```

Result:

```
[1, 3, '5x', 7, 9, 11, 13, '15x', 17, 19, 21, 23, '25x', 27, 29]
```

Explanation:

1. ```
    numbers = range(1, 31, 2)
   ```

   This creates an iterable with odd numbers from 1 to 29 without having to do:

   ```
   numbers = list(range(1,31))
   odds = [number for number in numbers if number % 2 == 1]
   ```

   which is redundant. The syntax for the range function is `range(start, stop, step)`, so for odd numbers from 1 to 30, it'll be `range(1, 31, 2)` which will give 1, 3, 5, 7, and so on.
2. ```
   res = [str(i) + 'x' if i%5 == 0 else i for i in numbers]
   ```

   I'm assuming you know how to use list comprehensions since you've used it in your code. The above line of code simply searches for a value that is divisible by 5 and adds an `x` to this value, else it simply adds `i` to the list.

   You can also use [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) instead of `str(i) + x` (as Stuart suggests under Jensen's answer):

   ```
   res = [f'{i}x' if i%5 == 0 else i for i in numbers]
   ```